# Me too Button vs. Up-voting

Tags: social-media, social

I came across this new community UI component: http://community.lithium.com/t5/Lithium-s-View-blog/Me-Too-now-available-on-Lithosphere/ba-p/38854

I'm wondering if others in the UX community have seem similar "Me too" buttons and if so...

How is this is different from up-voting or "likes"?

Are there other examples of this in the social media space today?

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that this kind of feedback doesn’t include a reputation system built on numeric points. There is no user profile dashboard counting number of “me too” or getting badges for five “me too” clicks.  This is (as I understand it) just a way to recognize the post as helpful without having to add a comment. It is very similar to the Facebook like – but to differentiate themselves from Facebook in their pursuit to be original they have chosen another label.

Other examples of not using a numeric voting system is what Microsoft uses in their different communities. This is more specific, asking more than one user (and not only the asker) “Did this solve your problem?” and “Was this helpful?” since an answer can be helpful but not solving the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how "Me Too" makes any sense. I think "Like" or an up arrow, or a thumbs-up button are the best ways to go. People are familar with the concept of a "Like", not so much with "Me Too".

Comment: In this context, the community is geared more towards support. The idea is that users will click "Me too" instead of replying "Me too!!!!!" or the user may be indicating that this post needs support staff attention.

Comment: @AaronBenjamin - Maybe in this case a "I'm having the same problem" button followed by a counter "X people have the same problem" might be a better solution